# How to describe prototypal inheritance in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, prototype

The code below is valid Javascript. Typescript, reasonably, doesn't understand B's `this.a` references and calls them out. Is there some type-fu that can be applied to B to explain the run time circumstances to Typescript and get the benefit of type-safety (e.g. an error if trying to access `this.c`)?

```js
const A = {
  a: 1,
  bar() {
    this.a = 10;
  },
};

const B = {
  b: 2,
  f() {
    console.log(this.a + this.b);
  },
  bar() {
    super.bar();
    console.log(this.a);
  },
};

Reflect.setPrototypeOf(B, A);
B.f(); // 3
B.bar(); // 10
```

Comment: Can you make them classes? I mean, the `bar` method on `const A` isn't type safe in your example, `this` is `any`

Comment: @Adam in my IDE, `this` inside `bar()` on `const A` is inferred by the compiler to be `{ a: number; bar(): void; }`, not `any`.

Comment: @jcalz - can't say I dove too deep, I just opened a new stackblitz typescript project and it showed up as `any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way you're going to get something like this to work (without having to explicitly write out redundant type annotation information everywhere) is if you refactor the assignment of `B` and setting of its prototype into a single function call like this:

```
function setPrototype<T extends object, U extends object>(
  object: T & ThisType<T & U>,
  proto: U
) {
  Reflect.setPrototypeOf(object, proto);
  return object as T & U;
}
```

If you call `setPrototype({...}, proto)`, where `{...}` is some object literal of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T`, and where `proto` is some other object of generic type `U`: the compiler will set the object literal's prototype to `proto` and return it.

In this call, you will see that the object literal will get a [contextual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) type for `this` which is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of both `T` *and* `U`.  This happens via [the magic `ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype).  When I say "magic" here, I mean that, unlike most other utility types, you could not define an equivalent type yourself.  The compiler literally gives special contextual powers to `ThisType<T>`; see [microsoft/TypeScript#14141](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14141) for a description of how this works.

Finally, the returned object type will also have that `T & U` intersection typing, so you can access both its own-properties and the properties inherited from the prototype.

---

Let's try it out:

```
const A = {
  a: 1,
  bar() {
    this.a = 10;
  },
};

const B = setPrototype({
  b: 2,
  f() {
    console.log(this.a + this.b);
  },
  bar() {
    super.bar();
    console.log(this.a);
  },
}, A);


B.f(); // 3
B.bar(); // 10
```

Looks good!  There are now no errors, and the compiler infers a contextual type for `this.a` and `this.b` inside the implementation of `f()`.

---

There are caveats and edge cases.  The intersection type `T & U` might not be completely accurate, but it's as close as I can easily represent.

The bigger caveat here is that there doesn't seem to be a way to handle `super` in a type-safe way.  Without something like a `super` parameter annotation (as asked for in [microsoft/TypeScript#42327](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42327)), there's no way to do it manually.  And even if you could do it manually, it still wouldn't get you to the automatic contextual typing of `ThisType<T>`... you'd need a new magical type alias like `SuperType<T>` also.  So for now, this seems to be beyond TypeScript's abilities.

Personally, I'd suggest moving away from this kind of manual prototype juggling in favor of `class`-based inheritance, since there's been much more work put into TypeScript to support ES2015+ inheritance than there has been to support ES5-.  But you presumably have your reasons for doing it this way; hopefully the above code will get you closer to having useful type safety.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQAoCc5VwTwAdUAeAFUVQA8pUwATZROAIwCtVoAaRAVUpp1GzdpygA+ABQBYAFCIRHaAC5EFAGRqAFjGRkipDX3E9COPKt4BKRAG85CgEqpgAGzEA6NJnMFiAeWBJViUoU18rAG4HRCx0ECwkELFEAEMmI15o2QBfOXzZCARkKEQAQUQAXjsY1NUARi4YllSsSRt7eQVEKB1kD1SqxHqABmyFHKbc7LkisBLEACEh72xcP1RJToUWVQAmKYUgjpiFOeQ4dw9XOABzSV7dAcQAah6+jxYomMnm1vaal0FMgQMQsJ9-t8gYhzpdUNc7g8PqkoRMppNylCCosPMdIogAPQExAAZjkOJabSihOJowKQA)